# Is it a good idea to mix React and Vue?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, architecture, frameworks, frontend

My company has a dev team in another country and they insist on using Vue for building new modules on top of our existing platform. Our main platform is a single page app built on React with Redux.

Is mixing frameworks based solely on the team's skills a good idea? Is it even feasible to do for these two frameworks?

Comment: The question is, why would you need to work on a project with two frameworks of such kind? Just wondering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**If the main reason is "I already know Vue" then I would say no.**

If they already know Vue it should be fairly easy to learn react.

I think both frameworks can work together, you can have a small feature in your React app built with Vue because even though your SPA is in React, a Vue component/app can be targeted to any html element and have that to be it's only scope.

**This scenario would be a good use case for mixing both frameworks:**

Lets say you already have a Vue app that calculates the best way to fill a truck with boxes of different sizes and it's sort of complex in terms of logic and UI, but really isolated from the rest of the logic in your app in that case I think embedding a Vue component/app into your React SPA would be nice because you won't have to build it again.

**Example of how the scope of the Vue component is limited:**

```
<div id="app">
  {{ message }}
</div>

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  }
})
```

In this case you will have a Vue component that only renders hello world.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/

Comment: Thanks. What if they had to build new components from scratch? The new module they are supposed to be building doesn't exist yet. They are saying that they need to build these features using Vue in order to meet business deadlines. Is there a huge disadvantage for Vue developers to have to follow our existing React framework? We already have CI and unit tests, while they have neither of these. I don't even think they use linters

Comment: I would build new components in React in this specific case. However in this case I would be very careful imposing short deadlines, that will probably lead to poor software which will become hard to maintain and buggy. A poor implementation will cost way more than taking the time to build it / architect it correctly since the beginning. I would stick with React in this case and have code reviews before merging any new features to master.

Comment: You might also be interested in the [micro-frontends](https://micro-frontends.org) concept