# Can Vue.js be used to build a Pluggable component across frontend frameworks

Tags: vue.js, frontend

I would like to build a pluggable component (preferably in vue) that is going to be used across projects with different frameworks.

```
global.app = () => {
    new Vue({
        el: element,
        components: { App },
        template: '<div><App/></div>',
    });
};
```

I tried instantiating the above vue instance directly into a react component and angular component. It seems to work fine.

I had read articles about plugging vue in react (vuera, react-vue), angular and angularJS. However, I am not sure what kind of performance tradeoffs this idea can bring in.
Is it a good idea to have two different frameworks working together? How else to approach this problem?

Comment: that depends to your scicumstances this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51219255/is-it-a-good-idea-to-mix-react-and-vue) can help you

Comment: I think you can use new vue cli 3 for that. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nSmMkeNjjPg